# insert data from select query results with other external/posted variables

Tags: php, sql, pdo

how can i insert data from query results and other variables in one insert query?

sample:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];  
$address = $_POST['address'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO info_table(fname, lname, address, email) VALUES (SELECT fname, lname, FROM info WHERE id = '$id')";  
$result = db->prepare($query);  
$result->execute();
```

how can i insert `$address` and `$email` together with the select results variables?

Comment: You should validate those posts, use htmlspecialchars like this: `htmlspecialchars($_POST['id'], ENT_QUOTES)` etc. It's against SQL injections and other evil stuff

Comment: While I agree that you should use some kind of application-specific filters on the external data, htmlspecialchars() makes sense before echo, but not before inserting into a data base.  PHP filter_var() is your friend.

Comment: Since he is preparing statements, no filtering really needs to be done.  He just needs to prepare the statement correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO info_table (
    fname, 
    lname, 
    address, 
    email
) 
SELECT 
    fname, 
    lname,
    ':address',
    ':email' 
FROM 
    info 
WHERE 
    id = ':id'
```

You aren't using the prepare right here.  You really should bind to the paramters `:address`, `:email`, and `:id`

```php
$result = db->prepare($query);  
$result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Do you need a table name for the INSERT statement?

Answer (score -1):

Answering precisely to your question:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MyInsecureTable (fname, lname, address, email) SELECT fname, lname, '$address', '$email' FROM info WHERE id = '$id'";
```

But it is scares the . out of me.

Comment: Your code is insecure and open to SQL injections and simple mysql errors. See other posts for escaping sql parameters, correct usage of PDO etc